# Запуск программ на linux нажатием мышки(g++)

Tags: c++, linux, g++, linux-mint

Чтобы открыть скомпилированную в g++ программу, вынесенную с помощью -о output в отдельный файл, надо в терминале набирать ./output . Как запускать программу щелчком мыши.

Comment: возможно Вам понравится такая комбинация `g++ test.cpp -o output && ./output` - скомпилировать и запустить, если компиляция удачна

Comment: @KoVadim программа компилируется и сразу запускается, однако при щелчке мышью запускаться не хочет

Comment: я думаю, она запускается. проверьте список процессов.

Comment: Вы бы уточнили, а где это Вы мышкой щёлкаете? В окошке какой программы?

Comment: @Sergey просто на рабочем столе

Comment: @neo Вы же говорите про линукс? На рабочем столе лежат файлы типа *desktop*. Что бы оконный менеджер этого рабочего стола запустил программу, указанную в этом *.desktop* файле, надо просто щёлкнуть по иконке. В некоторых окружениях один раз, в других окружениях требуется двойной клик. И комментарий *arrowd* абсолютно справедлив.  Т.е. вам нужно открыть редактор меню, найти там свою программу, редактировать её элемент и взвести галку "консольное приложение". После этого скопировать элемент меню на рабочий стол. Как это делается конкретно - по разному в разных оконных менеджерах.

Comment: Установите себе mc (midnight commander) -- это существенно облегчит Вам жизнь в линуксе.  В нем и мышкой можно запустить Вашу программу и клавишей Enter.

Comment: @Bwana The Master спасибо

Comment: Ни в коем случае не устанавливайте midnight commander, хотя... если у вас полно времени и нет желания понять, что происходит в тех или иных ситуациях, то да, можно и на синие окошечки подсесть.

Answer (score 7):

Ну вообще, просто щелчком. Однако на Unix-подобных ОС нет различия между "консольными" и "графическими" приложениями, как на Windows. Поэтому, при нажатии в файловом менеджере, ваша программа запускается, просто для нее не создается отдельное окно консоли, и вы не видите ее вывод.

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы создавалось отдельное окно консоли?

Comment: А это уже зависит от оконной среды, которую вы используете. В KDE4, например, при клике правой кнопкой в меню был пункт "Run in Konsole`. Что-то аналогичное должно быть и в Gnome, я думаю.